# How to run a go binary as last stage of Jenkins pipeline locally?

Tags: bash, go, jenkins, makefile, jenkins-plugins

I have a [simple gin gonic microservice Golang project](https://github.com/eduFDiaz/golang-microservices/blob/master/mvc/app/app.go) that I'm using to learn how to make a Jenkins pipeline. Every stage is successfully run, but the binary is not running after the pipelines finished. Can also tell the process is not running by using curl to hit the endpoint:

> curl http://localhost:9191/users

This is the pipeline in question:

```
pipeline {
   agent any

   stages {
      stage('git') {
         steps {
            echo "git"
            git 'https://github.com/eduFDiaz/golang-microservices.git'
         }
      }
      stage('clean') {
         steps {
            echo "clean"
            sh "make clean"
         }
      }
      stage('test') {
         steps {
            echo "test"
            sh "make test"
         }
      }
      stage('build') {
         steps {
            echo "build"
            sh "make build"
         }
      }
      stage('run') {
         steps {
            echo "run"
            sh "make run"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

The Makefile:

```
executableName=testApi
clean:
    echo "stoping if running and cleaning"
    rm -rf ./bin
    killall $(executableName) || true
test:
    echo "Testing..."
    go test -coverprofile cp.out ./mvc/...
    go tool cover -html=cp.out
build:
    echo "Building..."
    go build -o bin/$(executableName) mvc/main.go
run:
    echo "Running..."
    ./bin/$(executableName) &
all: test build run
```

Everything runs perfectly when I do it by hand. What am I missing here?

Console Output:

```
Started by user Eduardo fernandez
Running in Durability level: MAX_SURVIVABILITY
[Pipeline] Start of Pipeline
[Pipeline] node
Running on Jenkins in /root/.jenkins/workspace/golang pipeline test
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (git)
[Pipeline] echo
git
[Pipeline] git
No credentials specified
 > git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
 > git config remote.origin.url https://github.com/eduFDiaz/golang-microservices.git # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from https://github.com/eduFDiaz/golang-microservices.git
 > git --version # timeout=10
 > git fetch --tags --force --progress -- https://github.com/eduFDiaz/golang-microservices.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* # timeout=10
 > git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/master^{commit} # timeout=10
 > git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/origin/master^{commit} # timeout=10
Checking out Revision bfa434ff2aca9ea748182aa2b29094e1b9f442c6 (refs/remotes/origin/master)
 > git config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
 > git checkout -f bfa434ff2aca9ea748182aa2b29094e1b9f442c6 # timeout=10
 > git branch -a -v --no-abbrev # timeout=10
 > git branch -D master # timeout=10
 > git checkout -b master bfa434ff2aca9ea748182aa2b29094e1b9f442c6 # timeout=10
Commit message: "run reverted to previous state in Makefile"
 > git rev-list --no-walk bfa434ff2aca9ea748182aa2b29094e1b9f442c6 # timeout=10
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (clean)
[Pipeline] echo
clean
[Pipeline] sh
+ make clean
echo "stoping if running and cleaning"
stoping if running and cleaning
rm -rf ./bin
killall testApi || true
testApi: no process found
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (test)
[Pipeline] echo
test
[Pipeline] sh
+ make test
echo "Testing..."
Testing...
go test -coverprofile cp.out ./mvc/...
?       github.com/golang-microservices/mvc [no test files]
?       github.com/golang-microservices/mvc/app [no test files]
?       github.com/golang-microservices/mvc/controllers [no test files]
ok      github.com/golang-microservices/mvc/domain  0.004s  coverage: 0.0% of statements
ok      github.com/golang-microservices/mvc/services    0.003s  coverage: 0.0% of statements [no tests to run]
?       github.com/golang-microservices/mvc/utils   [no test files]
go tool cover -html=cp.out
HTML output written to /tmp/cover914928629/coverage.html
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (build)
[Pipeline] echo
build
[Pipeline] sh
+ make build
echo "Building..."
Building...
go build -o bin/testApi mvc/main.go
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (run)
[Pipeline] echo
run
[Pipeline] sh (hide)
+ make run
echo "Running..."
Running...
./bin/testApi &
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
Finished: SUCCESS
```

Comment: Can you provide the error?

Comment: there are no errors. All the stages run successfully

Comment: I just added the console output. Any idea what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem is occurring because Jenkins is cleaning all the child process started during build.. i.e. make run is bringing up the application but Jenkins is killing the process as part of cleaning (For More details search for "ProcessTreeKiller").

To Resolve update your line as below

```
stage('run') {
steps {
echo "run"
sh "export JENKINS_NODE_COOKIE=dontKillMe; make run "
}
```